# "Not under version control" error for force command in subversion

Tags: svn

HI All,

When iam executing svn force command given below  on some path, iam getting the below error
Please do let me know how to resolve this issue
Command:

```
set SVN_PATH=C:\main\test
svn lock [--force] "%SVN_PATH%" -m "lock before commit"
```

Error:

```
svn: 'C:\main\test\[--force]' is not under version control
```

Comment: Based on the command you are typing in, and your responses to the answers, you seem to not really understand Subversion.  I strongly recommend that you read the SVN book (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).  Pay particular attention to chapter 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
svn lock [--force] "%SVN_PATH%" -m "lock before commit"
```

should be:

```
svn lock --force "%SVN_PATH%" -m "lock before commit"
```

The square brackets area documentation convention indicating optionality. But frankly, if you didn't know that I wonder if you understand why you might use the lock command.

Comment: iam using lock because , what ever checking in to subersion are dll's. Checking build output to subversion is required for us becasue from here only we will deploy to our enviorments.

Comment: I removed the square brackets still iam getting that error. Please do let me know how to fix that issue.

Comment: But why do you need to lock before commit?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t include the square brackets in the command, they are just to indicate that the `--force` argument is optional.

But why are you locking the repository?

Comment: Directory is under version control only. Iam copying the output generated from build to subversion Directory , then executing the force command on whole Directory. Next step is committing the directory to subversion.